# SQL or No SQL database for this use case?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a new project and this is my use case. In a table, I need to store the following fields.

```
teamName - varchar
caseId - varchar
startTime - long (epoch) 
endTime - long (epoch) 
status - varchar
```

For a given input (team, timeInEpoch), I would want to query like this

```
Select * from table 
where teamName = team and 
startTime between timeInEpoch and currentTime or
endTime between timeInEpoch and currentTime
```

The table would be containing around 30k rows at any given time and can go to a maximum of 50k (since I plan to have some cleanup jobs to backup the data).

Can you please suggest if I should be using a sql or a no sql database for this approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the table is really small and you do not state any special high throughtput requirements I would suggest to use SQL.
I think you are choosing between SQL and DynamoDB, so I just want to tell you that your condition is not easy to implement in DynamoDB. You will need split each record into two and do 2 query to use query and not scans (to save money). It will be not so easy to implement and maintain and I see no reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly straightforward use case that any database would be able to handle.  Consider that using a new technology can have a steep learning curve.  Don't overlook the power of working with what you already know.

On the other hand, if you've got the flexibility (e.g. time) to learn a new technology, it can be a great way to gain new skills and experience.

This is a pretty simple use-case (a single access pattern), so perhaps you could give both a try?